# TFS custom CheckInPolicy run nodejs command

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, eslint

Currenly I'm trying to execute ESLINT on check-in operations in order to check common issues.

To do so I create my CheckInPolicy class and in the `Evaluate` method, for js files I execute the following code:

```
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + string.Format(@"ESLINT ""{0}""", checkedPendingChange.LocalItem))
            {
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => sb.AppendLine(e.Data);
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

            // We may not have received all the events yet!
            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                stringCollection.Add(string.Format(@"ESLINT check failed for {0}{1}{1}{2}", checkedPendingChange.LocalItem, Environment.NewLine, sb.ToString()));
```

Then I packed this assembly and its registration in a VSIX and installed it in my machine.

Sadly when I check-in a js file the command fires, but the exit code is always **1**...

ESLINT and all its dependecies is installed globally and if I run the same code in a console application is working fine (the exit code is **0** or **1** accordingly), Visual Studio 2015 is runnig ad Admin.

IS the correct way to launch a ESLINT? Or I have to check Edge.js? Can be missing %PATH% related issue?

Comment: no need to call `cmd /c`, just call eslint directly. Though what you're doing is not recommended as the policy can be evaluated multiple times and should return very quickly. Instead write the output to a log and verify the log is newer than the files, tell the user to rebuild if that's not the case.

Comment: @jessehouwing I can't call ESLINT directly, it return me error...thanks for the help, but I need to set it as policy and I'll add a custom button on Visual Studio to call ESLINT before to check-in